# Sentences in newer Cobol versions

Tags: cobol

Cobol sections and paragraphs are subdivided into sentences. In older Cobol versions (without explicit scope delimiters e. g. `END-IF`) defining multiple sentences per section/paragraph was required to limit the scope of conditional statements (e. g. `IF`).

Are there any use-cases where defining multiple sentences is required in newer Cobol versions? Or are sentences just there for historical reason?

Comment: It's just for backwards compatibility. If scope-terminators are used, then you have no procedural statements which require full-stops/periods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bill Woodger says, sentences only exist now for backwards compatibility.

There is now only one place where multiple sentences must be used: in `DECLARATIVES`, where the `USE` statement must be in its own sentence.

```
DECLARATIVES.
a-file-error SECTION.
    USE ON a-file.
    DISPLAY "Oops"
    .
```

Comment: That's interesting for USE. IBM Enterprise COBOL has a couple of Extensions, which allow that the paragraph-name after the USE is missing (like your example, which is therefore non-Standard 85). It is not documented in Enterprise COBOL as required for USE, but indeed attempts to compile without it fail :-) I'd assumed that when present it was the full-stop/period that has to precede a label, but indeed it is bound to the USE. Learn something new every day :-) It's still not a line of procedure code, more like when EXIT had to be on its own, I suppose. Interesting.